# Javascript quitting on an ampersand "&"

Tags: javascript, html, escaping, ampersand

I'm trying to use this JS to open a new email on a client machine with the page title already populated in the subject line and body, called by this link `<a href="javascript:mailpage()">Email</a>`

```
function mailpage()
{ mail_str = "mailto:?subject= " + document.title; mail_str += 
"&body=Hi, I thought you might be interested in this: " 
+ document.title; mail_str += 
". You can check out the web site at "
+ location.href; location.href = mail_str;
}
```

But some of my pages have an ampersand & as part of the page title, and the function chokes on that and only inserts the text before the & and not the & or anything after. (Yes, "choke" is a highly technical term.)

Is there a way to escape the & so the JS doesn't choke? The & actually appears as `&#064;` in the page source. Or do I need to go to a php function?  Thanks.

**Edit: this works:** `+ encodeURIComponent(document.title); mail_str +=`

Comment: It works fine with me. You could try changing the & into &amp; though.

Comment: Could you try to urlencode the document.title?  (Not sure of the email client will properly decode it though...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
encodeURIComponent(document.title)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be calling [encodeURI](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuri.asp) or [encodeURIComponent](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp) on those variables you're inserting within the destination. This will eliminate the foul characters and allow it to pass through.

```
function mailpage()
{
    var subject = encodeURIComponent(document.title),
        body= encodeURIComponent("Hi, I thought you might be interested in this: "
            + document.title + ". You can check out the web site at "
            + location.href;

    location.href = "mailto:?subject= " +subject + "&body=" + body;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function mailpage()
{ mail_str = "mailto:?subject= " + document.title; mail_str += 
  "\&body=Hi, I thought you might be interested in this: " 
  + document.title; mail_str += 
  ". You can check out the web site at "
  + location.href; location.href = mail_str;
}
```

Use \ as the escape character in javascript

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with JS escaping, and everything to do with HTML entity escaping in the HTML tag's attribute.

Comment: Gotcha. Started my answer b4 I completely finished reading the question... my bad.  Retagging question for ya.